# page up in gnu screen with Shift-PageUp

Tags: gnu-screen, scrolling, termcap

In the Linux terminal the key sequence Shift-PageUp can often be used to scroll up.

However, this key sequence doesn't seem to work in gnu screen when ssh'ing to particular machines.

I have two questions. 1) Where is this key sequence defined? 2) What can I change in my screen settings to always allow this?

Does this have something to do with the termcap entries?

I am currently using three machines.  Two of which will scroll the buffer up when pressing Shift-PageUp.  One machine will not respond to the key press at all.

Working Machines:

- Centos 6.5
- Centos 5.9

Not working machine:

- Centos 5.9

Here is my .screenrc which I am using on all three machines

```
termcapinfo xterm|xterms|xs|rxvt ti@:te@

term screen-256color

hardstatus on
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string "%{= wb}%-w%{.yb}%n %t%{-}%+w %=%{b r} %H %{..b}[%l] %{..K}%C%a "

startup_message off

# turn off visual bell
vbell off

# Autodetach session on hangup instead of terminating screen completely
autodetach on 

# give more scroll back
defscrollback 20000

# turn on alternate screen support 
altscreen on

# bash will be replaced by the running command 
shelltitle " $ |bash"

screen 3
screen 2
screen 1
```

I'm not sure if it matters, but I am using ROXTerm as my terminal emulator.

Note: I know that Ctrl-A [ can be used to enter screen's copy mode scroll-back buffer.  However I don't want to use this.  I am interested as to why Shift-PageUp in screen works on some machines as expected, but is completely ignored on other machines.

Edit: I was able to solve this on the one machine it was not working on by changing the termcapinfo line in .screenrc to the following:

```
termcapinfo xterm*|xs|rxvt ti@:te@
```

On the one machine that didn't work, my $TERM environment variable was set to xterm-256color, so is it possible that there is no termcap/terminfo entry for "xterm-256color"?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46483/how-to-allow-page-up-in-gnu-screen . That question is asking how to scroll up using screen's copy mode, while this question is asking how to scroll up using the terminal's Shift-PageUp functionality.

Comment: not really a duplicate, shift+pageup is not a synonim of pageup .

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this helps (I don't know how to bind shift key) but I'm using:

```
bindkey ^[[5;5~ eval "copy" "stuff ^U"
bindkey ^[[6;5~ eval "copy" "stuff ^D"
```

in my .screenrc to bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>Page Down</kbd> to:

-entering "copy" mode

-pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>/<kbd>D</kbd> (since it's similar to Vim movement)

Comment: I specifically *do not* want to enter copy mode in screen.  I want the terminal to scroll up like ti normally does when pressing `Shift`+`Page Up`.

Comment: Still in "copy mode", but I got SHIFT page up/down to work as described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46483/how-to-allow-page-up-in-gnu-screen#comment1136229_165810